# How do ara::core types like ara::core::Vector support exception-less operations in Adaptive Autosar?

Tags: autosar

Adaptive AUTOSAR standardizes data types like ara::core::Vector, ara::core::Map etc. STL types like std::vector , std::maps may throw exceptions, how to use ara::ore types without handling exceptions ?

Comment: Maybe by checking return values/error codes before you go on with next statements? That's done for decades now, even in C++ with disabled exceptions. In AUTOSAR Adaptive, they also use non-default allocators.

Comment: Maybe. What about the plenty STL code mixed with ara code? Is there a standard in Autosar requiring exception-free?

Comment: Yes, ara::core must support exception less implementation along with the one with the support for exceptions.